# Mongodb: how to list type of a field?

Tags: mongodb

I've a field in a collection where
- in 99.9% of documents it's an array
- in 00.01% is a subdocument

Can I 
- LIST documents this field and a column that reports this field's type?
- and/or
- FILTER documents by the type of this field?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, with the `$type` operator:

#### To filter:

```
db.someCollection.find({ "fieldThatMightBeAnArray": {$type: 4} })
```

For a list of types (and string aliases), see [the documentation page on the query operator `$type`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/).

#### To list the type in a column:

You should be able to use the [`$type` aggregation operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/#example) in an aggregation query.

```
db.someCollection.aggregate([{
  $project: {
    "fieldThatMightBeAnArray": 1,
    "typeOfFieldThatMightBeAnArray" : { $type: "$fieldThatMightBeAnArray" }
  }
}])
```

(I did not test this last one myself)